# OCamlbuild and Building Native Dynamic Linked Library

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

I posted a [question on the ocaml listserv](http://old.nabble.com/Compiling-shared-library-with-ocamlopt-to32904338.html) that nobody responded to, I'm hoping someone here can either call me an idiot, confirm the situation, or offer up a creative solution.

When building a dynamic library through `ocamlbuild` I get stuck on the final linking line,

```
/opt/ocaml-3.12.1/bin/ocamlopt.opt -shared -verbose -cc gcc plugins/example.cmx -o plugins/example.cmxs -ccopt -v
+ as -o 'plugins/example.cmxs.startup.o' '/tmp/camlstartupe6993f.s'
+ gcc -o 'plugins/example.cmxs'   '-L/opt/ocaml-3.12.1/lib/ocaml' -v 'plugins/example.cmxs.startup.o' 'plugins/example.o'
```

This creates an error similar to [here](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=563481). This error is fixed when I remove the `-cc` option and the `-shared` flag gets passed to `gcc`.

```
/opt/ocaml-3.12.1/bin/ocamlopt.opt -shared -verbose plugins/example.cmx -o plugins/example.cmxs -ccopt -v
+ as -o 'plugins/example.cmxs.startup.o' '/tmp/camlstartup2c31a2.s'
+ gcc -shared -o 'plugins/example.cmxs'   '-L/opt/ocaml-3.12.1/lib/ocaml' -v 'plugins/example.cmxs.startup.o' 'plugins/example.o'
```

OCamlbuild passes the `-cc` option to everything, so removing that isn't an option. Seems like a bug in ocamlopt; has anyone experienced similar situations? Am I
missing anything or any options in compilation?

Thanks.

---

*EDIT*

My solution is just to pass the options via a flag in myocamlbuild.ml

```
flag ["shared"; "link"]
    (S [A"-ccopt";A"-shared"]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot reproduce here.

Ocamlbuild by itself doesn't pass the -cc option (why should it?) and I cannot find such behaviour in sources either. So it is probably passed by your plugin - and it is wrong, because ocamlopt determines the linker for shared libraries at configure time (usually it is `gcc -shared`), but if `-cc` option is specified explicitely - it will happily use that instead.

NB option `-shared` is not "passed" to ocamlopt, but instead it enables linking a dynamic plugin and this results in selecting special C linker for shared libraries (which happens to be gcc with the same-named option). Specifying `-cc` overrides it as a whole.

Comment: Yes it is passed to my plugin, but it's necessary. passing -ccopt/-cclib w/ -shared will fix the issue. I guess in choosing cc the shared option may not be available on that compiler. It looks like I can manage something with ocamlbuild though. thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. You should either pass -cc `somecc -shared` when building cmxs or not pass -cc at all.